# Can $R(3, 3, \ldots, 3)$ be replaced by $R(3, 3, \ldots, 3) - 1$ in the proof of Schur’s theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

[Schur’s theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem#Ramsey_theory) states that for any number of colors $c$, there is a number $N(c)$ such that if the numbers of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, N(c)\}$ are colored using $c$ colors, then there exist monochromatic $x$, $y$, $z$ where $x + y = z$.

There’s a “standard” proof of Schur’s theorem that I’ve found in multiple sources. ([Here’s one from Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Combinatorics/Schur%27s_Theorem); [here’s another;](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Evjungic/RamseyNotes/sec_SchurThm.html) [here’s another](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Elyall/REU/schur.pdf)) The idea is the following:

1. Pick $N(c) = R(3, 3, \ldots, 3)$. That is, pick $N(c)$ to be the smallest number where any $N(c)$-clique whose edges are colored one of $c$ colors contains a monochrome triangle.
2. Form an $N(c)$-clique as follows. The nodes are the numbers $1, 2, \ldots, N(c)$. An edge from $i$ to $j$ is given the color of the number $|j - i|$.
3. Obtain a monochrome triangle in the clique consisting of nodes $a$, $b$, and $c$, where WLOG we assume $a \lt b \lt c$.
4. Then $b - a$, $c - b$, and $c - a$ are all the same color, and if we pick $x = b - a$, $y = c - b$, and $z = c - a$ we have $x + y = z$.

There’s a small detail about this proof I’ve been wondering about. If you have the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, N(c)\}$ and form the clique as described above, then the number $N(c)$ itself is never used to color any of the edges, since $|i - j|$ is always between $1$ and $N(c) - 1$, inclusive. If we enlarge the clique to contain $N(c) + 1$ nodes, then all elements of the original set make an appearance somewhere as an edge in the clique.

However, if we do this, then setting $N(c) = R(3, 3, \ldots, 3)$ gives us a bigger clique than what we need. We can instead use $N(c) = R(3, 3, \ldots, 3) - 1$.

Does this edit to the “standard” proof work correctly?

I’m aware that this proof of Schur’s theorem still gives a fairly conservative upper bound on minimal size of $N(c)$, so this isn’t a major improvement over the original proof. It’s just something I’ve been curious about because I found it odd that the proof would exclude some element from participating in the clique coloring.

(It appears that some discussion to this effect appeared in [the comments on this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836820/schurs-theorem-proof-for-ramsey-theory-misunderstanding), though not in a huge amount of detail.)

Thanks!